# Do I need MD5 as a companion to SHA-1?

Tags: security, hash, md5, sha1, sha

Do I need **both** MD5 and SHA-1 values to be sure the downloaded file is

a) Untouched by hackers. For example, when I need to download some app's `.iso` via torrents

and

b) Not corrupted during technical issues? For example, some unstable network connection during download.

Or, probably, SHA-1 value will be enough for both checks?

Also, is SHA-1 (without MD5) enough to be sure that some file downloaded years ago and stored somewhere on my HDD haven't [degradated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation)?

Comment: This is not a programming question. But the attack on SHA-1 in early 2017 required "the equivalent processing power as 6,500 years of single-CPU computations and 110 years of single-GPU computations", so SHA-1 should be safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

From a security perspective MD-5 is utterly broken.

SHA-1 is considered suspicious, and avoided for most uses if at all possible. For new projects: don't use it at all.

SHA-2 (aka SHA-256, SHA-512, etc.) is still widely used for fast hashes.

SHA-3 is the future since 2012, nothing is stopping you from using it already. I see little reason not to use it for new projects.

What's the problem with older ones:

- Their resistance to finding collisions is below par: This is an attacker creating 2 contents that have the same hash. These are constructed at the same time. This problem is there for MD5 and SHA-1, and it's BAD, but requires the attacker creating both versions (and then they can do a switch at any time they want undetected).
- Their resistance to length extension attacks is relatively weak. This is especially true for MD5, but SHA-1 and even SHA-2 to some degree suffer from it.

When is it not a problem: to ensure your disk has not produced an error: and hash will do, even a simple CRC32 will work wonders (and I'd recommend the simpler CRC check), or a RAID array, as these can fix errors, not just detect them.

Use both ?
Well if you have to find a collision on one hash and have that same set of plaintexts also produce a collision on another hash, is probably more difficult. This approach has been used in the past, The original PGP did something like it. If I'm not mistaken it had a number of things it calculated, one of them simply the length (which would prevent the extension attack above).

So yes, it likely adds something, but the way md5 and SHA-1 and SHA-2 work internally is quite similar, and that's the worrisome part: they are too much alike to be sure just how much it adds against a highly sophisticated attacker (think the level of the NSA and their counterparts).

So why not use one of the more modern versions of SHA-2, or even better SHA-3 ? They've no known weaknesses and have been peer-reviewed heavily. As such for any commercial level use, they should be more than enough.

Refs:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sha-3